# why my magento 2 localhost setup in very slow?

Tags: magento2, cli, localhost, timeout

When i run cli cmds it's take to much time

```
  >php bin/magento s:s:d -f 



frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2918/2918           ===100% %  10 mins            
frontend/Solwin/kosmic_child/en_US      3088/3088           == 100% %  44 mins
```

it's more time and storage

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: it's not slow by default , there might be some changes you made that made it slow

Comment: Ubuntu 18.........

Comment: how are your caches enables/disabled?

Comment: enabled.........

Answer (score 0):

You have two option

1. run the command with -dmemory_limit=5G

   php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
2. Update your local system with SSD drive.

Comment: i have doubt what is SSD drive

Comment: Like a memory stick, there are no moving parts to an SSD. Rather, information is stored in microchips. Conversely, a hard disk drive uses a mechanical arm with a read/write head to move around and read information from the right location on a storage platter. This difference is what makes SSD so much faster.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9152/magento-server-upgrade-ssd-or-ram

Comment: I use ssd but disk usage stays on 0% through out magento surfing. any idea what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are in developer mode. You **should** not need to run SCD on you local, the files not being there will trigger Magento to symlink the files to the source files so any changes are immediate on refresh.